# How to show multiple images inside UIScrollView in iOS

Tags: iphone, imageview, scrollview

I am making one iPhone app in which i need to show some images inside UIScrollView, on left and right there will be two buttons user can click on button and it will show the next or previous image. Also at the bottom there is one button, when user will click on that button it will show the image which we have selected in scrollview.I would like to know how do we show multiple images inside that scrollview and while selecting bottom button, how to find which image was there inside scrollview.

Comment: Seems to get the direct code? Have did and work on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example from danielbeard.wordpress.com

In case your image names aren't just numbers:

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];

    NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++)
    {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [imagesArray count], scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: i did this and works fine for portrait mode. but how do i do it for landscape mode if i have different image array.? plz give some suggestion on this.

Comment: You should  detect when the screen is rotated to landscape mode. Once detected change the image names in the images array then remove the old scrollview and draw a new one with new image array.

Comment: i did the same yday only. anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: can you guide me to remove particular UIImageView?

Comment: @CodeHunterr the number of ImageViews created depends on the imagesArray (containing image names). So remove the image name that you don't want from the array.

Comment: @TanyaLertwichaiworawit How you are  managing memory in this case?

Answer (score 3):

have look on to this example:
http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/adding-a-uiscrollview-to-a-uiview-ios/

Comment: Ohh...this one completely solved the problem and +1 for that!

Answer (score 2):

**Apple.developer** [**PhotoScroller**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrates the use of embedded UIScrollViews and CATiledLayer to create a rich user experience for displaying and paginating photos that can be individually panned and zoomed.

CATiledLayer is used to increase the performance of paging, panning, and zooming with high-resolution images or large sets of photos.

Answer (score 0):

you just simply first 
   create a new view on runtime and image and assign tag all views like 1000 or 100 and increment on tag value and then add this view to scrollview and two buttons for left and right moving and make their outlet actions and add all the scrollview sub views in to an mutable array like this

```
     indexStart=100;
 UIView *AddView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 0, 100, 100)];

                AddView.tag=indexStart;
                btnTap.tag=indexStart;

                UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];



                [AddView addSubview:imgview];

                imgview.image=image;
                imgview.tag=1000;
               [ScrollView addSubview:AddView];
                [imgArray addObject:AddView];
```

you use loop to do this and on left and right button you use this code and in this code editImgeView is the image view inbetween left and right button where you show the image you just simple indexstart ++ or -- if user choose right or left button

```
for (int index = 0; index < [imgAddArrayAfter count]; index ++ ) {
         NSLog(@"index %d",index);
        UIView *vc=[imgArray objectAtIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"view tag %d",vc.tag);
        if(vc.tag == indexStart)
        {

            UIImageView *modalView=(UIImageView *)  [vc viewWithTag:1000];
            editImgeView.image=modalView.image;
        }
    }
```

i hope you understand ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 465);

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    NSMutableArray *arrImage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"food1.jpeg", @"food2.jpeg", @"food3.jpeg",@"food4.jpeg", @"food5.jpeg", @"food6.jpeg",@"food7.jpeg", @"food8.jpeg", @"foo9.jpeg",@"food10.jpeg", @"food11.jpeg", @"food12.jpeg",@"food13.jpeg", @"food14.jpeg", @"food15.jpeg", @"food16.jpeg", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrImage count]; i++)
    {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [arrImage count], scrollView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I think the problem with loading lot's of images in the scroll view still exists. If you ever want to load images in the scroll view you will face a problem of memory usage. The images most likely will consume most of your device's memory. The only way of doing is to create reusable scroll view that works similar to the uitableview - the scroll view that has pool of views (with images) ready to display. This can be quite complex to create.

I have created open source project to support reusable loading images in the scroll view. It is very easy to implement. You need to call couple of delegate and data source methods and that's it. There is also sample project for obj-c and swift in order to make easy to understand. Please feel free to contribute. I hope it will be useful.

here is a source: https://github.com/sumofighter666/ReusableScrollView